# React Native: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: reactjs, xcode, cocoapods, native, exit

So, I just created a new React Native using react-native init projectName, then I got an error of type cli is not a function and whatnot. So I used react-native init projectName --version 0.68.2, and successfully  managed to create a new project

On Android it runs perfectly, but iOS it's giving me the Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rcD9.jpg)

So I tried sudo get install cocoapods,

cd ios && rm -rf build/
cd .. $$ pod install